# Normalize the lambda operation across different objects

Tags: function, lambda, functional-programming

In the code below, you can see a common lambda operation happening for multiple maps with different objects. I would like to know if I can define a common function when called which does perform the same operation.

```
Map<Int, Object1> map1.entrySet()
                      .stream()
                      .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().getDisplayName()))

Map<Int, Object2> map2.entrySet()
                      .stream()
                      .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().getDisplayName()))

Map<Int, Object3> map2.entrySet()
                      .stream()
                      .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().getDisplayName()))
```

In the above, object1, object2 and object3 are of different types(class).

Assume that all the objects obj1, obj2, obj3 have the property displayName in common.

Comment: Do `Object1/2/3` share any interface? If not, are the types of their `getValue()` the same?

Comment: No for both. That's the problem. If the getValue() is same, doesn't that mean the objects are of the same class? I want a method which accepts a map with different class objects and perform the above operation.

Comment: I misunderstood and thought `getValue` was a method on `Object1`, not on `Entry`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do without reflection is to pass a lambda for getting the property:

```
public <K, T1, T2> Map<K, T2> mapValues(Map<K, T1> source, Function<T1, T2> function) {
    return source.entrySet()
                 .stream()
                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> function.apply(e.getValue())));
}

// use
mapValues(map1, Object1::getDisplayName)
mapValues(map2, Object2::getDisplayName)
```

(Kotlin has the equivalent of this method in the standard library)

*With* reflection, you can do

```
public <K, T> Map<K, String> mapDisplayName(Map<K, T> source, Class<T> clazz) {
    Method m = clazz.getMethod("getDisplayName");
    return source.entrySet()
                 .stream()
                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> (String) m.invoke(e.getValue())));
}

// use
mapValues(map1, Object1.class)
mapValues(map2, Object2.class)
```

But it is less safe and less generally useful in exchange for... not being that much more convenient.